# Django: i want to get a render a page according to specific userid obtained from another page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a page called userid.html in which a user is entering the userid. If this user id exists, he is taken to next page, sec.html where he is asked a security question which he has already set.

this security question is a context variable, and i need to render this page according to user id given in the previous page(userid.html), as security question of each user will be different.

How can this be done in django?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the view, when you navigate from page1 to page2, can you not just have a simple call and put the security question in the context there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would be to pass in the user ID as a query parameter to the next page, i.e. if the user starts at page `http://myserver/userid.html`, and enters a user ID of 1234, then they're redirected to the page `http://myserver/sec.html?userid=1234`.

The second page can access the query parameter via the HttpRequest.GET dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by session tracking. [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html)  explains it well.